# How can I add an event to a calendar using zenity?

Tags: linux, unix, zenity

zenity --calendar
   The rest I dont know what to do. There is a command called pal and Gcal but i dont think we are allowed to use it for our project.

Comment: What do you mean by `add an event`? Do you want to highlight a given day in the calendar applet?

Comment: so I select a date. Then i click OK and its prompts me a text box to input my event(a birthday or a meeting, etc...) Then its saves it and I should be able to see it when I click on that date again. And the date where there is an event should be highlighted.